# I need to show short month name

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, user-interface, format

[image]

```kotlin
private fun joinedDate(date: String): String {
    val a = LocalDateTime.parse(
        date,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
                         .withLocale(Locale.getDefault())
    )

    val date = "${a.month.toString().lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }}, ${a.year}"
        
    return date
}
```

This is my code i need to show month short name (e.g. *Jan* for January)

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired output? I mean a full one, like `Jan 2022`…

Comment: I have added the exact output

Comment: OK, thanks, could you please add an example input? How is your zone offset formatted?

Answer (score 0):

You can build and use a suitable `DateTimeFormatter` that only prints the short month-of-year, a comma and the year…

```kotlin
val dtfOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                 "MMM, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH
             )
```

… and then use it in the method [`LocalDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-).

It will print the desired result if the object actually has a *month-of-year* and a *year*.

If you don't know the offset format, use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` in order to build up a maximally flexible `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing. Otherwise just use the one shown in your question.

Full example:

```kotlin
import java.util.Locale
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder

/* 
  define the output formatter
  (short month, year, English)
 */
val dtfOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)

/* 
   prepare a formatter that is able to parse many
   different offsets and no offset at all
 */
val dtfIn = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .optionalStart()
                    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                    .appendOffsetId()
                .optionalEnd()
                .appendOptional(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                        "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
                    )
                )
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

// conversion method
private fun joinedDate(date: String): String {
    // just parse, format and return
    return LocalDateTime.parse(date, dtfIn)
                        .format(dtfOut)
}

// try with some different input values
fun main() {
    val someDateTimes = listOf(
        "2022-10-18T21:43:10.111+00",
        "2022-10-18T21:43:10.111+0000",
        "2022-10-18T21:43:10.111+00:00",
        "2022-10-18T21:43:10.111Z",
        "2022-10-18T21:43:10.111"
    )
    
    someDateTimes.forEach { println("${joinedDate(it)} <-- $it") }
}
```

Output:

```
Oct, 2022 <-- 2022-10-18T21:43:10.111+00
Oct, 2022 <-- 2022-10-18T21:43:10.111+0000
Oct, 2022 <-- 2022-10-18T21:43:10.111+00:00
Oct, 2022 <-- 2022-10-18T21:43:10.111Z
Oct, 2022 <-- 2022-10-18T21:43:10.111
```